# Read doctype with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, doctype

Is the doctype part of the DOM, and if so, is there a good cross-browser way to read it?  I'm not trying to do anything fancy.  I just want to access the doctype information from within some JavaScript code.  Read-only access is fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`document.doctype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.doctype) seems to be the (read-only) property you're looking for.

Comment: Specifically, the optional `DocumentType` node is a `childNode` of `Document`, just as the root `documentElement` and any `Comment` nodes outside the root are.

Comment: Thank you, Alex.  bobince, the comment you left is also very informative.

Comment: Yeah, IE mis-parses the doctype as a comment. You can still find it through the `childNodes` list and read the content of the declaration as the comment's `data`, but you can't tell for sure that it wasn't actually a comment, and IE discards the leading and trailing two characters, assuming they're both going to be `--`. Ah, IE, bless it...

Comment: Is it possible to get `document.doctype` as a string somehow? And I don’t mean this one: `"[object DocumentType]"`

Comment: +1 for Mathias's question. Is it posibl to get document.doctype as a whole doctype string both in FF, IE, Chrome and Webkit? Or should this be a separate question?

Answer (score 2):

If you're inspecting the DOCTYPE to determine if you're in quirksmode or not, this is known to be cross-browser:

```
document.compatMode; // returns either "BackCompat" or "CSS1Compat"
```

So you can do:

```
var quirksmode = document.compatMode == "BackCompat";
```

Comment: This isn't working completely either. IE thinks a simple <!DOCTYPE> (no DTD or anything) means the page is CSS1Compat. God how I loathe IE.