# What would be your take on Doctype version detection?

Tags: javascript

What would be your take on Doctype version detection. One solution comes to mind – feature detection, but is that the correct way to go? What I need in particular is to know wether the document is HTML4, XHTML (don't need the version) or HTML5.

Ideas?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987493/read-doctype-with-javascript

Comment: As in that question, you can look for the `DocumentType` node to find out for sure, except on IE where it mis-parses a doctype as a comment, which you then have to examine using crude text-searching hacks. Feature-detection would absolutely be better, but what feature are you looking for? Browsers will typically treat HTML4.01-Strict, XHTML1.0-Strict and HTML5 documents identically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not really universal, but: http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/520145-doctype-detector