# Doctype sniffing with CSS3, and specifically with Mojo::DOM

Tags: html, perl, css, mojolicious, mojo-dom

I can use [Mojo::DOM](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::DOM) and its CSS3 selectors to figure out the DOCTYPE of an HTML document? Related to my other question, [How should I process HTML META tags with Mojo::UserAgent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32472378/how-should-i-process-html-meta-tags-with-mojouseragent) where I want to set the character set of a document, I need to know what to look at and [doctype sniffing](https://hsivonen.fi/doctype/) seems to be the way to do. HTML and HTML 5 have different meta tags for charsets in HTML when the document setting overrides the server setting (or non-setting).

I don't have a problem accomplishing the task since I can grab the raw response and play with regexes to look at the DOCTYPE. [Since the browser DOMs seem to be able to get the DOCTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987493/read-doctype-with-javascript), I'm infected with the idea that I should be able to get it. However, the lack of examples leads me to think nobody does it in the way I think I should do it.

I tried lots of stupid ways but my CSS kung fu is weak:

```
use v5.20;

use feature qw(signatures);
no warnings qw(experimental::signatures);

use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $html );

say "<title> is => ", $dom->find( 'head title' )->map( 'text' )->each;

say "Doctype with find is => ", $dom->find( '!doctype' )->map( 'text' )->each;

say "Doctype with nodes is => ", $dom->[0];

__DATA__

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>This is a title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Level 1</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

When I dump the `$dom` object, I see the DOCTYPE in the tree:

```
$VAR1 = bless( do{\(my $o = bless( {
                      'tree' => [
                                  'root',
                                  [
                                    'text',
                                    '',
                                    ${$VAR1}->{'tree'}
                                  ],
                                  [
                                    'doctype',
                                    ' html',
                                    ${$VAR1}->{'tree'}
                                  ],
```

Now how do I get at that?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a built-in way of doing this, as the doctype is stored at the top level of the tree.  The best I could come up with was to do: `my %ugly_tree = @{ $dom->root->tree }; my ($doctype) = $ugly_tree{doctype};`  But this may be brittle.

Comment: The doctype is just another node and you can use methods like [child_nodes](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM#child_nodes) to find them.

Answer (score 2):

Determining the encoding of an HTML5 document is very [complex](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#determining-the-character-encoding). I'm afraid [Mojo::DOM](http://mojolicio.us/perldoc/Mojo/DOM) is only a fragment parser, and therefore we've decided that a full implementation of the encoding sniffing algorithm would be out of scope. Most of the web is thankfully UTF-8 encoded, and i imagine that's why this question doesn't come up very often.

Comment: My problem is a bit easier: I only want to determine what they say the charset is even if it is wrong. There's a particular mis-configured web server that motivated this problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

I still think there's hope for a better way to do this, but perhaps I'm putting too much responsibility on [Mojo::UserAgent](http://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo::UserAgent). I can build a transaction and add a `finish` event to the response. In that event, I sniff the content with a regular expression and add an `X-` header with the doc type. I could probably pass the info in some other way, but that's not the point (still taking suggestions though!)

```
use v5.14;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

@ARGV = qw(http://blogs.perl.org);

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

my $tx = $ua->build_tx( GET => $ARGV[0] );
$tx->res->on( finish => sub {
    my $res = shift;
    my( $doctype ) = $res->body =~ m/\A \s* (<!DOCTYPE.*?>)/isx;
    if( $doctype ) {
        say "Found doctype => $doctype";
        $res->headers->header( 'X-doctype', $doctype );
        }
    });
$tx = $ua->start($tx);

say "-----Headers-----";
say $tx->res->headers->to_string =~ s/\R+/\n/rg;
```

Here's the output:

```
Found doctype => <!DOCTYPE html>
-----Headers-----
Connection: Keep-Alive
Server: Apache/2.2.12 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 20624
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-doctype: <!DOCTYPE html>
Last-Modified: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 13:08:26 GMT
ETag: "26d42e8-5090-51fdcfe768680"
Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2015 13:40:02 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=15, max=100
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Now I have to think about various things to parse the `DOCTYPE` values and decide based on those what to do with content.